# Error while starting hadoop daemons (ConnectionRefused and ExitCodeException)

Tags: hadoop

I am getting some errors while staring hadoop daemons. I have configured Hadoop 2.7.1 on Solaris 10 server. When I am doing `start-dfs.sh` and checking with `jps` it is showing only datanode and secondaryNamenode as running process and the namenode is not getting started. It is giving `ExitCodeexception` while starting namenode but when I checked the logs for Datanode and SecondaryNamenode, it shows following errors:

**SecondaryNamenode log:**

```
2015-12-08 10:27:51,646 ERROR
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
java.net.ConnectException: Call From psdrac2/192.168.106.109 to psdrac2:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getTransactionId(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getTransactionID(NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getTransactionID(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.countUncheckpointedTxns(SecondaryNameNode.java:641)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.shouldCheckpointBasedOnCount(SecondaryNameNode.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:393)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:361)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:357)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:609)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:707)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1529)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1446)
... 18 more
2015-12-08 10:28:52,695 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:28:53,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:28:54,719 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:28:55,731 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:28:56,743 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:28:57,754 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:28:58,766 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:28:59,778 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:29:00,789 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:29:01,801 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

**Datanode log:**

```
2015-12-08 10:26:13,703 INFO
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-12-08 10:26:16,710 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-12-08 10:26:18,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-12-08 10:26:19,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-12-08 10:26:19,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2015-12-08 10:26:19,124 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockScanner: Initialized block scanner with targetBytesPerSec 1048576
2015-12-08 10:26:19,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is psdrac2
2015-12-08 10:26:19,183 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2015-12-08 10:26:19,359 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened streaming server at /0.0.0.0:50010
2015-12-08 10:26:19,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s
2015-12-08 10:26:19,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Number threads for balancing is 5
2015-12-08 10:26:20,029 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2015-12-08 10:26:20,087 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2015-12-08 10:26:20,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.datanode is not defined
2015-12-08 10:26:20,185 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2015-12-08 10:26:20,201 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context datanode
2015-12-08 10:26:20,202 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2015-12-08 10:26:20,203 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2015-12-08 10:26:20,310 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 40263
2015-12-08 10:26:20,310 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2015-12-08 10:26:23,001 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@localhost:40263
2015-12-08 10:26:23,969 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.DatanodeHttpServer: Listening HTTP traffic on /0.0.0.0:50075
2015-12-08 10:26:24,727 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnUserName = hadoop
2015-12-08 10:26:24,728 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: supergroup = supergroup
2015-12-08 10:26:25,027 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2015-12-08 10:26:25,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 50020
2015-12-08 10:26:25,322 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:50020
2015-12-08 10:26:25,401 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
2015-12-08 10:26:25,554 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
2015-12-08 10:26:25,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000 starting to offer service
2015-12-08 10:26:25,663 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2015-12-08 10:26:25,665 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2015-12-08 10:26:27,848 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:28,860 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:29,872 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:30,884 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:31,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:32,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:33,919 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:34,931 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:35,942 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:36,954 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:36,964 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000
2015-12-08 10:26:42,986 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:43,998 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:45,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:46,022 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:47,034 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:48,046 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:49,058 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:50,069 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:51,081 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-12-08 10:26:52,093 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: psdrac2/192.168.106.109:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Also I am getting error while starting namenode. (I already posted question for the same [ExitCodeException while staring namenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126781/exitcodeexception-while-staring-namenode) , but I did not get any response from anyone).

If anyone knows anything about this error and have any idea about how to resolve this error please help me out of this.

Comment: Can you paste core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files?

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju for configuration files core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml, check my previous post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126781/exitcodeexception-while-staring-namenode)

Comment: Can you paste the complete namenode log?

Comment: Ok I will edit it into my question

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju I was trying to update my question with full log of Namenode but it is exceeding the character limit. How do I post the full log?

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju check out the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126781/exitcodeexception-while-staring-namenode) I have updated the full log of namenode

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same config parameters in [ExitCodeException while staring namenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126781/exitcodeexception-while-staring-namenode) mentioned in the post, you should specify resource manger ( parameters which i specified in above link post) where to run. Then start services

Comment: But why its refusing the connection. Why that ConnectionException is occurring in SecondaryNamenode logs though it is showing SeconaryNamenode as running process after doing `jps`

Comment: Did you check the ssh connection between the nodes..?

Comment: I have done single node configuration. and between the nodes means exactly which node?

Comment: As observed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126781/exitcodeexception-while-staring-namenode log file, you set replication is 3. But here you are using single node, If you set this to a value higher than the number of available slave nodes (more precisely, the number of DataNodes), you will start seeing a lot of “(Zero targets found, forbidden1.size=1)” type errors in the log files. Change the replication to 1 and try

Comment: I checked out some information regarding ConnectionException on [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused), there they mentioned  **Check that there isn't an entry for your hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts** and when I check my /etc/hosts file there it is mentioned 127.0.0.1     localhost. So should I need to remove that line? I mean what is with it?

Comment: replace localhost like `127.0.0.1 psdrac2` and `192.168.106.109 psdrac2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97370/discussion-between-krishna-and-sarika-ovahal).

Answer (score 0):

Use below configs

core-site.xml
    `<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS.name</name>   ----fs.default.name (depricated in 2.x)
    <value>hdfs://hostname:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/data/tmp</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>`

mapred-site.xml
    `<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>`

hdfs-site.xml
    `<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/data/nn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/data/dn</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>`

yarn-site.xml
    `<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the line 
hdfs://hostname:9000

to

hdfs://localhost:9000
in core-site.xml

Comment: can you check port 9000 is open,try changing the port number to 8020

Comment: can you post  : core-site.xml,mapred-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml